# How to validate txt and csv files while uploading without checking extensions/headers/hex code in .netcore application?

Tags: csv, file, asp.net-core, text, file-extension

I want to check the real content type of the file getting uploaded on my servers. I only want text and csv files. Extensions/headers and hex code of a file can be changed. Is there any other method to validate the files?
I am using asp.net core framework for my application.

Comment: You have two ways to do that, you can check the [`ContentType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8#definition)  under  [`HttpFileCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8#definition), or check the  [`Mime Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775107(v=vs.85)#remarks)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron If my file has one million records, the session will be timed out for checking the content type. 
If someone changes the file header manually, then it will consider the file as a text file and the fill will get uploaded on the server.

Comment: In that case you have to seach your expected file extension on your code specifically.